# Customize Antd in ejected CRA

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

I've got a fresh CRA made, and I am using the Ant Design library.
Looking at the instructions, it's not 100% clear to me what exactly I need to do, however from what I can gather, since I have ejected my app, I can modify my webpack.config.js file and be done with it.

Unfortunately, it seems the changes I have made are not being reflected

I have added the below into my rules array

```
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [{
        loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
      }, {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'), // translates CSS into CommonJS
      }, {
        loader: require.resolve('less-loader'), // compiles Less to CSS
        options: {
          modifyVars: {
            'primary-color': '#1DA57A',
            'link-color': '#1DA57A',
            'border-radius-base': '2px',
          },
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      }],
    },
```

Does anyone know how I can get this working please?

Comment: Bit late to the party but might help others: After adding the webpack rule as above, you need to also swap the antd.css file import to the .less version in your app jsx/js file:(import 'antd/dist/antd.css' > import 'antd/dist/antd.less')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ejecting. You can use `customize-cra` package to override default settings. Ant design has already added the docs on the usage for create react app. Please check this [link](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Customize-Theme).

Hope this helps!